# Bundle products added programmatically not showing in fronend, magento issue

Tags: php, magento, csv

I have added bundled products by fetching data from the CSV. Products added in this manner are visible in admin panel but not in front end. I have gone through all the threads but got no solution. Please help me with this situation.

```
require_once($magentoPath . 'includes/config.php');
  require_once($magentoPath . 'app/Mage.php');
  $storeID = 1;
  $websiteIDs = array(1);
  $cats = array("12");

  Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

  $productCheck = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

  $p = array(
    'sku_type' => 0,
    'sku' => '687',
    'name' => "BarProduct",
    'description' => 'Foo',
    'short_description' => 'Bar',
    'type_id' => 'bundle',
    'attribute_set_id' => 4,
    'weight_type' => 0,
    'visibility' => 4,
    'price_type' => 0,
    'price_view' => 0,
    'status' => 1,
    'created_at' => strtotime('now'),
    'category_ids' => $cats,
    'store_id' => $storeID,
    'website_ids' => $websiteIDs
  );

  $productCheck->setData($p);
  Mage::register('product', $product);
  $optionRawData = array();
  $optionRawData[0] = array(
    'required' => 1,
    'option_id' => '',
    'position' => 0,
    'type' => 'select',
    'title' => 'FooOption',
    'default_title' => 'FooOption',
    'delete' => '',
  );

  $selectionRawData = array();
  $selectionRawData[0] = array();
  $selectionRawData[0][] = array(
    'product_id' => 337,
    'selection_qty' => 1,
    'selection_can_change_qty' => 1,
    'position' => 0,
    'is_default' => 1,
    'selection_id' => '',
    'selection_price_type' => 0,
    'selection_price_value' => 0.0,
    'option_id' => '',
    'delete' => ''
  );
Mage::register('productCheck', $productCheck);
 Mage::register('current_product', $productCheck);
 $productCheck->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(false);
 $productCheck->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
  // Set the Bundle Options & Selection Data
  $productCheck->setBundleOptionsData($optionRawData);
  $productCheck->setBundleSelectionsData($selectionRawData);
  $productCheck->setCanSaveBundleSelections(true);
  $productCheck->setAffectBundleProductSelections(true);

  $productCheck->save();
  $indexer = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer');
foreach ($indexer->getProcessesCollection() as $process) {
    $process->reindexAll();
}
```

- Please note that wherever If I re-save my product through admin panel it starts displaying on front-end.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Mage::register('product', $product);` => `Mage::register('product', $productCheck);`

Comment: Thanks a lot dear, There was one more problem, the product was out of stock. to make it in stock:       $productCheck->setStockData(array(       'is_in_stock' => 1,   'qty' => 12 ));